# Unexpected result when attempting to add an object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Just a bit confused as to why the following is occurring:

```
let groupdetails = {
      groupName: "",
};    
const groupsArray = [];

groupdetails.groupName = 'A'
groupsArray.push(groupdetails)
groupdetails.groupName = 'B'
groupsArray.push(groupdetails)
console.log(groupsArray)
```

The result I am getting is:

```
[ { groupName: "B" }, { "groupName": "B" } ]
```

The result I was expecting was:

```
[ { groupName: "A" }, { "groupName": "B" } ]
```

Unsure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are pushing _the same_ object to the array twice. `groupsArray[0] === groupsArray[1]`. Create a new object in the middle and you'll get what you want.

Comment: @CherryDT - could you please assist with what you mean about creating a new object?

Comment: `groupdetails = { groupName: 'B' }` instead of `groupdetails.groupName = 'B'`; or adding `groupdetails = { ...groupdetails }` before the `groupdetails.groupName = 'B'` - otherwise you are accessing the same `groupdetails` that you just pushed and change it (and push the same thing a second time afterwards) - pushing the object won't create a copy, the element in the array points to the same object that your variable also points to at that point

Comment: Maybe this helps to understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a different reference each time you push an element

```js
let groupdetails = {
      groupName: "",
};    
const groupsArray = [];

groupdetails.groupName = 'A'
groupsArray.push(groupdetails)
groupdetails = {...groupdetails}
groupdetails.groupName = 'B'
groupsArray.push(groupdetails)
console.log(groupsArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are facing issue with [Shallow Copy and Deep Copy.](https://medium.com/@manjuladube/understanding-deep-and-shallow-copy-in-javascript-13438bad941c).

In your case eventhough you were updating the value `groupdetails.groupName = 'B'`, this referes to the same node as the one you pushed initially. You have to creat a new node with spread operater or some thing and update its value and push it again.

In order to achieve your requirement you have to follow something like below mentioned.

```js
let groupdetails = {
  groupName: "",
};
const groupsArray = [];

groupdetails.groupName = 'A'
groupsArray.push(groupdetails);
const newNode = { ...groupdetails };
newNode.groupName = 'B';
groupsArray.push(newNode);
console.log(groupsArray);
```

Comment: What happens if I need to push an unknown number of groupdetails, i.e. C, D, etc ?

Comment: @ArthurJ You can either go with this way or can do directly ['A', 'B', 'C'].forEach(node => groupsArray.push({
  groupName: node,
})};

Answer (score 1):

Remember Arrays, Objects are copied by references, not just by values

```
a = 'John';
b = a;
console.log(a === b);
```

Here values are copied to another variable.

```
obj = {name: 'John'};
newObj = obj;
newObj.name = 'Kate';
console.log(newObj);  // {name: 'Kate'}
console.log(obj)      // {name: 'Kate'}
```

Here the reference is passed to the other object. So once an object is modified it will be reflected on the other object.

In your case, this will work,

```
const groupsArray = [];

function addNew(value) {
    return { groupName: value}
}

groupsArray.push(addNew('A'));
groupsArray.push(addNew('B'));
console.log(groupsArray);
```